# Google Fit - Get and Display only steps from the sensor and not from user input

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

How do we fetch steps only recorded by the sensor(using the History API) and ignore any user input steps similar to what the Health Mate app does when you link it to Google Fit?

I have tried demos and the github demos of Google Fit including the sensor API, recording API and step counter API. I am unable to distinguish between the two

Once we add an activity manually we always end up getting a merged value and there is no break-up of the various types i.e stream type Step counter or stream type user_input.

These are some of the links I have referred to.

[How to differentiate between manual added steps and sensor recorded steps in Google Fit Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093789/how-to-differentiate-between-manual-added-steps-and-sensor-recorded-steps-in-goo?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Google Fit Api filter manually added activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119448/google-fit-api-filter-manually-added-activities)

[How to identify google fit activity is entered manually or tracked by sensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451851/how-to-identify-google-fit-activity-is-entered-manually-or-tracked-by-sensor)

https://plus.google.com/u/0/105650643673857572241/posts/fET6zKYFq4K

Comment: Based from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729379/steps-count-using-sensor-with-google-fit), the **sensor API** is use to get the data from the sensor such as user's heart rate, the **Recording API** is used to collect the data, such as the geolocation data when user running is, and a **History API** is used to edit the record data. Please check the solution offered for more details.